# Tikz: Using an already defined \node label in \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using tikz to draw a mathematical structure. I have labelled all my nodes in my code and I want to use them as arguments in the \draw command but I keep getting this error "! Missing \endcsname inserted." Below is a minimum working example. Kindly help me with this.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
Putting node and clipping them to their respective positions
\foreach \x in {2,3,4,...,14}
    \foreach \y in {2,3,4}
    {
        \node [circle,draw=white,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1.8mm] (u\x\y) at (\x,\y)  {};
    }
%Drawing arrows
\foreach \x in {3,5,...,11}
    {
    \v = \x + 1;
    \draw[->>] (u\x3) -- (u\v2) ;
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where did you find this code: `\v = \x + 1;` ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Also, was the "Putting node..." supposed to be a comment?  Anyway, the fact that the first loop didn't generate any errors indicates that \x and \y are macros (text).  Therefore to compute \x+1 you must convert \x from text to a number, add one, then convert back to text again.  I tried using \pgfmathparse and \pgfmathresult, but got 4.0 instead of 4.

Comment: BTW, you can place an * between \x and \y.  It is a legal name character, but not a legal macro name character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another option without extra variables:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Putting node and clipping them to their respective positions
\foreach \x in {2,3,4,...,14}
    \foreach \y in {2,3,4}
    {
        \node [circle,draw=white,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1.8mm] (u\x\y) at (\x,\y)  {};
    }
%Drawing arrows
\foreach \x  in {3,5,...,11}
    {
      \draw[->>] (u\x3) -- (u\number\numexpr\x+1\relax2) ;
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Putting node and clipping them to their respective positions
\foreach \x in {2,3,4,...,14}
    \foreach \y in {2,3,4}
    {
        \node [circle,draw=white,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1.8mm] (u\x\y) at (\x,\y)  {};
    }
%Drawing arrows
\foreach \x in {3,5,...,11}
    {
      \pgfmathparse{\x+1}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\v}{\pgfmathresult}
      \draw[->>] (u\x3) -- (u\v2) ;
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: arrows]